# when i try to install composer require riazxrazor/payumoney it gives me an error

Tags: php, laravel, payumoney

I want to install  **riazxrazor/payumoney** for **laravel 5.8** but when I try to install `composer require riazxrazor/payumoney` it gives me an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/650VP.png)

Comment: run this command ` composer dump-autoload ` and make sure if your laravel version is below 5.2 then you must add that Facade in app configuration

Comment: but i want to run my project only on laravel 5.8.so is it possible to install riazxrazor/payumoney for laravel 5.8??

Comment: Then you just need to run that command and it should work. make sure that you also import it top in your Controller

Answer (score 1):

This package isn't compatible with Laravel 5.8.

The Composer error message says `symfony/http-foundation` is the problem. This can happen when two projects--Laravel, and this Composer package--require different versions of the same library.

Laravel 5.8's [Illuminate\Http](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/composer.json#L21) requires:

```
"symfony/http-foundation": "^4.2",
```

[riazXrazor/payumoey](https://github.com/riazXrazor/payumoey/blob/master/composer.json#L23) requires:

```
"symfony/http-foundation": "~2.6|~3.0"
```

The package would need to be updated to support newer versions of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

For this package([riazxrazor/payumoney](https://packagist.org/packages/riazxrazor/payumoney)), you just have to run this command at your command prompt

```
composer require riazxrazor/payumoney
```

After, you need to add this line in the provider section. 
Open the `config/app.php`:

```
Riazxrazor\Payumoney\PayumoneyServiceProvider::class,
```

add this line in the `aliases` section:

```
'Payumoney' => Riazxrazor\Payumoney\PayumoneyFacade::class
```

---

Also, you have to fulfill the requirement of this package [riazxrazor/payumoney](https://packagist.org/packages/riazxrazor/payumoney)

**requires**

```
php: >=5.5.0
symfony/options-resolver: ~2.6|~3.0
symfony/http-foundation: ~2.6|~3.0
```

Comment: it gives me this error.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/http-foundation (locked at v4.3.4, required as 3.0) is satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.3.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.3.4 requires symfony/http-foundation ^4.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, 4.3.x-dev, 4.4.x-dev].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.3.4 requires symfony/http-foundation ^4.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, 4.3.x-dev, 4.4.x-dev].

Comment: @Dhanashri The error indicates not fulfill the requirement of  package